# Erlang stop gen_server

Tags: erlang, gen-server

I have gen_server:

```
start(UserName) ->
    case gen_server:start({global, UserName}, player, [], []) of
    {ok, _} ->
        io:format("Player: " ++ UserName ++ " started");
    {error, Error} ->
        Error
    end
    ...
```

Now i want to write function to stop this gen server. I have:

```
stop(UserName) ->
    gen_server:cast(UserName, stop).

handle_cast(stop, State) ->
    {stop, normal, State};
handle_cast(_Msg, State) ->
    {noreply, State}.
```

I run it:

```
start("shk").
Player: shk startedok
stop(shk).
ok
start("shk").
{already_started,<0.268.0>}
```

But:

```
stop(player).
ok
```

is work.

How can i run gen_server by name and stop by name?

Thank you.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First: You must always use the same name to address a process, `"foo"` and `foo` are different, so start by having a strict naming convention.

Second: When using globally registered processes, you also need to use `{global, Name}` for addressing processes.

In my opinion you should also convert the `stop` function to use `gen_server:call`, which will block and let you return a value from the gen_server. An example:

```
stop(Name) ->
    gen_server:call({global, Name}, stop).

handle_call(stop, _From, State) ->
    {stop, normal, shutdown_ok, State}
```

This would return `shutdown_ok` to the caller.

With this said, the `global` module is rather limited and alternatives like `gproc` provides much better distribution.

Comment: gen_server has special function for doing this stop/1, stop/3 http://erlang.org/doc/man/gen_server.html#stop-1

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the docs infront of me, but my guess would be that you need to wrap the username in a global tuple within the gen_server cast.