# Erlang cast message to global gen_server

Tags: erlang, gen-server

it's continue of previos [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5726481/erlang-stop-gen-server)

I have gen_server:

```
start(UserName) ->
    case gen_server:start({global, UserName}, player, [], []) of
    {ok, _} ->
        io:format("Player: " ++ UserName ++ " started");
    {error, Error} ->
        Error
    end
    ...
```

How correctly send message to this gen_server. For example: in another file i make:

```
gen_server:cast(test, message).
```

In my gen_server file i have:

```
handle_cast(message, State) ->
    io:format("Message receiving \r\n"),
    {noreply, State};
```

I start my gen_server with test name:

> server:start(test).
>   test started

when i call `gen_server:cast(test, message).` it is nothing output in shell. How can i check handle_cast calling or not?

Thank you.

Comment: Rather than using printouts, why not to use tracing instead? http://aloiroberto.wordpress.com/2009/02/23/tracing-erlang-functions/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of

```
gen_server:cast(test, message).
```

write

```
gen_server:cast({global, test}, message).
```

If you register name as {global, name} you must call it as {global, name}

If your handler is called it will print "Message receiving \r\n" in shell. You made that with io:format call.

Comment: Well, it will actually just crash - io:format takes two arguments. Additionally, it will print out wherever its group leader prints, which may or may not be the shell you're in.

Comment: there are functions io:format/1 and io:format/2, so it won't crash. At least not on io:format call.

Comment: Yep, you're right - io:format/1 will work fine. I would be tempted to suggest using error_logger:info_msg/2 instead of io:format for this kind of thing as the output almost always goes somewhere useful. This is not necessarily the case for just a plain io:format call.